# Most efficient way to perform this task in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a list of customer_id as well as the name of the product they have purchased product_name.

product_list = ['hat','pants','shoes','tie'] in A-Z order

| customer_id | product_name |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | shoes |
| 001 | tie |
| 001 | hat |
| 002 | shoes |
| 002 | tie |

What is the most efficient way in Pyspark to make a cross sell table so it looks like this?

|  | hat | pants | shoes | tie |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hat | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| pants | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| shoes | 1 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| tie | 1 | 0 | 2 | 2 |

The way to interpret that is reading from the first column: of all the customers who bought a hat this is how many also bought the item in the other columns

So customers who bought a hat also in total bought 1 tie

Answer (score 1):

You can use `crosstab` with `join`. It generates the crosstab based on the values in the provided columns.

```py
data_sdf. \
    join(data_sdf.withColumnRenamed('prod', 'prod2'), ['cust_id'], 'left'). \
    crosstab('prod', 'prod2'). \
    show()

# +----------+---+-----+---+
# |prod_prod2|hat|shoes|tie|
# +----------+---+-----+---+
# |       hat|  1|    1|  1|
# |       tie|  1|    2|  2|
# |     shoes|  1|    2|  2|
# +----------+---+-----+---+
```